# Dynamically add member function to an instance of a class in Python

Tags: python

When I do the following:

```
class C:
 pass

def f( self ):
 print self

a = C()

a.f = f

a.f()
```

I get the following error at the line a.f():
TypeError: f() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

The problem appears to be that when f is added to the instance, a, it is treated like a function that is stored inside of a, rather than an actual member function. If I change a.f() to a.f(a), then I get the intended effect, but is there a way to make python interpret the original example this way? In other words, is there a way to add a member function to an instance of a class at runtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For Python 2.X you can use:

```
import types
class C:
    pass

def f(self):
    print self

a = C()
a.f = types.MethodType(f,a)
a.f()
```

For Python 3.X:

```
import types
class C(object):
    pass

def f(self):
    print(self)

a = C()
a.f = types.MethodType(f,a)
a.f()
```

Comment: This is the way to add the function to the specific instance `a`
(other instances of class `C` won't have `f`).

Comment: `C.f = types.MethodType(f,None,C)` would be the code to add the function to any existing or eventual new instances of the class C

Comment: What python version is this for? the `print` statement suggest python 2.*. Doesnt work in python 3.

Comment: @LudvigH: I have modified my answer to include support for python 3.X.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for pointing this out it's hard to remember if old answers need to be updated.

Answer (score 5):

You should put `f` in the class, not in the instance...

```
 class C:
     pass

 def f(self):
    print(self)

 a = C()
 C.f = f
 a.f()
```

For the interpreter `myObject.foo()` is the same as `myClass.foo(myObject)` when the object doesn't hold anything named `foo`, but a function placed inside a object is just a function.

Comment: This is the way to add the function to all instances of class `C` (and it's sub-classes).